# Programmatically pull data types for MS SQL table columns for later insertion

Tags: c#, .net, database

Rails has an awesome way of looking up column names and expected datatypes from the DB, alleviating a lot of programming.

I'm trying to build something like this in C#.NET, because we have large tables that are ever changing. I'll be adding parameters like so:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("parametername", *SqlDbType.Int*);
param.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
param.Value = 0;
comm.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Notice the SqlDbType.  How can I get that?  If I get DataColumns from the DataSet, all I can get is System types like System.string.

Answer (score 2):

why not just let ADO.NET detect it automatically:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter("parametername", value);
```

'course, you don't actually need Direction, either:

```
comm.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("parametername",value));
```

I'm kind of a fan of doing things in one line :)

Answer (score 1):

For our project we query the `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` tables before we build our SQL statements.  If you stick the value in `DATA_TYPE` from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` into an `Enum.Parse` that should give you the correct value.